# Can I add an Angular2 (click) to a Google maps marker infoWindow?

Tags: google-maps, angular

I have implemented Google maps in Angular2 without using any of the npm libraries available and need to add a button to the infoWindow that fires an Angular function. Can this be done???.

My best effort so far does not work, the airport.name shows but the (click)="setAirport('departure', airport)" does not. I assume it's not connected to Angular in any way.

My component has the following function when the user clicks to activate the marker & infoWindow.

showAirport(idx, airport) {
    const markerInfo =
    `<h4>${airport.name}</h4><div class='row' style='margin:0; margin-top:20px'>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="setAirport('departure',airport)">Set as Departure</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" (click)="setAirport('arrival',airport)">Set as Arrival</a>
    </div>
    </div>`

;

```
this.setCurrentAirport(idx);
this.infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this.markers[idx]);
```

}

Here is more of the component ts file.

---

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;

    map: any;
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    private allItems: any[];

    lat = 51.5287718;
    lng = -0.1;

    airports = [];
    markers = [];
    flights = [];
    polylines = [];

    bounds = {
      w: 0,
      e: 0,
      n: 0,
      s: 0
    };

    loadAirports(apiBounds) {
        this.airportsService.byBounds(apiBounds)
        .subscribe(
          (airportData: any[]) => {
              for (let i = 0; i < airportData['data'].length; i++) {
                  const tmpAirport = {
                      id: i,
                      airportID: airportData['data'][i].id,
                      name: airportData['data'][i].airportName,
                      lat: airportData['data'][i].lat,
                      lng: airportData['data'][i].lng
                  };
                  this.airports.push(tmpAirport);
                  this.addMarker(tmpAirport, tmpAirport['name'], i);
              }
          },
          (error: Response) => {
            const errorData = error.json();
          }
        );
    };

  showAirport(idx, airport) {
    console.log(airport);
    // this is where I want to be able to include the buttons 
    const markerInfo = `<h4>${airport.name}</h4>`;
    this.infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
    this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this.markers[idx]);
  }

  loadMap() {
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51, -0.5);
    const mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      scrollwheel: false,
      zoom: 9,
      minZoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

    new google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'bounds_changed', () => {
        this.loadAirports(this.bounds);
    });
  }

  addMarker(airport, info, markerIndex) {
    const position = new google.maps.LatLng(airport['lat'], airport['lng']);
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: position,
      markerIndex: markerIndex
    });
    const markerInfo = '<b>' + airport.name + '</b>';
    this.addInfoWindow(marker, markerInfo, markerIndex);
    this.markers.push(marker);
  }

  addInfoWindow(marker, content, markerIndex) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      this.infoWindow.setContent(content);
      this.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
  }

}
```

Comment: I would use https://angular-maps.com/ - will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit too far in for what would be quite a core change

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: There's a lot of it so spinning up a plunkr  is a bit involved but here is a stripped down version of the ts file.

Comment: add into the original post

Comment: It's a tricky one because as you said you're not fully integrating with Angular. Could you maybe add `#infoWindow` to the element then in your component do `@ViewChild('infoWindow') InfoWindow: any` and use that to get to the native element and listen for clicks. Sorry not the best help perhaps someone wiser will come along :) Edit: plunkr might be your best bet to get more help

Comment: That might be a good approach although I think I might have to add the # to each of the buttons and listen to those as I need two events fired, one departure and one for arrival airports.

Comment: Thanks for the input, if that works out I'll allocate the fix over to you :)

Comment: No worries, it might be that nothing is available once you're inside the map.

Comment: Had another thought - what about using a component as a button i.e. `<my-button (buttonClicked)='doStuff()'></my-button>` then on said component doing a `@HostListener('click', ['$event'] public buttonClicked(e) { buttonClicked.emit('CLICKED!)}` - a shot in the dark :D

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution, but you could always assign clases/ids to the buttons inside the InfoWindow, and then bind to them:

```
showAirport(idx, airport) {
  console.log(airport);
  // this is where I want to be able to include the buttons 
  const markerInfo = `
    <h4>${airport.name}</h4>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="departure-button">Set as Departure</a>
  `;
  this.infoWindow.setContent(markerInfo);
  this.infoWindow.open(this.map, this.markers[idx]);

  const departureButton = this.mapElement.nativeElement.getElementById('departure-button');
  departureButton.onclick = this.setAirport('departure', airport);

  google.maps.event.addListener(this.infoWindow, 'closeclick', () => {
    departureButton.onclick = null;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign this to that and use it,

```
  addInfoWindow(marker, content, markerIndex) {
    let that = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      that.infoWindow.setContent(content);
      that.infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });
  }
```

Crazy right ;). variable scope for `this` is not the `this` that you need so this don't have `infoWindow` but by assigning `this` to `that` now we have `infowWindow`.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, which is about how to bind to a button within the InfoWindow

Comment: Do you try me code or you just comment and down vote ?

Comment: Did you read the question before answering? your code is already in the question, and does NOT answer how to bind to a button within the InfoWindow, soooooooo downvote

Comment: FYI, doing `() => {}` already assigns a `_this` to replace the `this` within the callback, so the `let that = this` is useless.

Comment: Thanks I see it now, I was answering anther problem not the main one, but about `let that = this` can you explain more plz.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions